# TypeError: n.querySelectorAll is not a function d3 js Unit test using Jest in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, d3.js, jestjs

I want to write Unit test cases for d3.js file using jest in Vue.js project.

I have an import d3 library in my project.

**Test.js file**

```
mouseOver = function (d) {
        if(options.showNodeDescription) {
            d3.select("#nodeText").text(d.name);
        }
        d3.select(this).selectAll('image')
            .style("display",function(k) {
                let className = d3.select(this).attr("class");
                return (k.type == 'source' && className == 'addIcon') ? 'none' : 'block';
            });
    },
```

**Test.spec.js**

```
it('should call mouseOver to be defined', ()=> { 
      global.document = {
        getElementById: jest.fn(() => {}),
        getElementsByClassName : jest.fn(() => {}),
      };
          let d = {name : 'test' }
            document.body.innerHTML= `<image class="addIcon"  xlink:href="assets/img/icons/add-icon.svg" x="75" y="65"></image>`; 
              var circle = d3.select(this).selectAll("image");
              expect(circle.empty()).toBe(true);
          expect(termConnections().mouseOver(d)).toBeDefined;
      });
```

**Error facing:**

```
TypeError: n.querySelectorAll is not a function

     d3.select("#nodeText").text("");
                  }
                 d3.select(this).selectAll('image')
                                   ^
                           .style("display", "none");
           },
```

How can I write unit test cases for this file?